# Extracting subscript and superscript

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an expression in the form

```
Power[Subscript[g,a],mu]
```

and I need to extract "a" and "mu" from this expression. It should be very simple but I could not find it in the Internet.

Comment: `Extract[Power[Subscript[g, a], mu], {{1, 2}, {2}}]`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Actually it does not work. Suppose I have `y=FullForm[x]` here it gives `Power[Subscript[g, a], mu]`. But then `Extract[y, {{1, 2}, {2}}]` does not work. It says `Part 2 of Power[...] does not exist`.